# Expose containers using Agent IPs and configure them in Azure application gateway's backend pool

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-container-service

I have created an Azure container service cluster using Kubernetes orchestration with 3 Masters and 2 Agents:

```
NAME                       STATUS    AGE       VERSION
k8s-agentpool-75930632-0   Ready     4d        v1.7.9
k8s-agentpool-75930632-1   Ready     4d        v1.7.9
k8s-master-75930632-0      Ready     4d        v1.7.9
k8s-master-75930632-1      Ready     4d        v1.7.9
k8s-master-75930632-2      Ready     4d        v1.7.9
```

Private IPs for agents `k8s-agentpool-75930632-0` and `k8s-agentpool-75930632-1` are `10.0.0.4` and `10.0.0.5` respectively.

I want to deploy containers using agent IPs and make use of them in the Azure application gateway's backend pool.

How to do that? Please share your knowledge and kubectl/docker command if you have faced a similar requirement.

Comment: Whatever you connect to the cluster you should connect it to the exposed load balancer endpoint Kubernetes gives you (`kubectl expose service ...`), connecting straight to the nodes defeats the whole purpose of having Kubernetes run your app. You should also ask yourself, do you really need that App Gateway on top?

Comment: I have been using application gateway connected with exposed load balancer endpoint currently, and would like to move away from the middle man (load balancer).